# How overlap navbar with a video in Bootstrap 5.3?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm refactoring a website using Bootstrap and I need a navbar with a video in background.

I set the navbar as sticky top to keep it always on top even if I scroll.

I succeeded after several tests by setting the video as `position: absolute` and moving the video before the navbar.

But there was a problem. When I tried to insert other code after the navbar, the items went under the video.

So I removed the `position: absolute` from the video and put the navbar before the video.

I can not in any way to make it work. Could someone more experienced with bootstrap help me?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- SECTION NAVBAR -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md sticky-top" style="background: none; transition: 1s;" id="navbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80" alt="Top Life" style="width: 40%; height: auto;">
    </a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" id="nav-link1" href="#">Servizi</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" id="nav-link2" href="#">Tecnologia</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" id="nav-link3" href="#">Immonbili</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" id="nav-link4" href="#">News</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" id="nav-link5" href="#">Identità</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" id="nav-link6" href="#">Contatti</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" id="nav-link-dropdown">
            <ion-icon name="globe-outline"></ion-icon>
          </a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Italiano</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">English</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- SECTION VIDEO -->
<video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
        <source src="/img/0314_compressed.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The result should be something like this:

[image]

Comment: The web is full of tutorials on how to create a transparent navbar with a full-screen image or video. Could you not find any?

Comment: Next time edit the snippet rather than the raw post markup so you don't destroy the demo.

Answer (score -2):

In the Nav tag use

```
style=position:"fixed";
background:"transparent";
```

This will make the navbar to get fixed at the top and the background will be transparent and hence the video will be visible as background.

Comment: Answers should be more specific and detailed. Please see [answer] and take the [tour].